# How to find unlinked fields on a clone?

Tags: powershell-extensions, item-clones

I am writing a Sitecore PowerShell Extensions script to determine which fields on a cloned item are unlinked from its original item. The easiest check is to compare the field value of the original and the cloned item. However, it is possible for the fields to have the same value but be unlinked, such as when the cloned item field is modified, saved, and then edited to be the same value as before.

What would the script look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$field.ContainsStandardValue` as follows:

```
function Find-UnlinkedFields {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
    [Sitecore.Data.Items.Item]$ClonedItem
  )

  if (-not $ClonedItem.IsClone) {
    Write-Host "Item is not a clone"
    return
  }

  $unlinkedFields = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]

  foreach ($field in $ClonedItem.Fields) {

    # OPTIONAL: skip standard fields. Could also perform other checks such as $field.Shared and $field.Unversioned
    if ($field.Name.StartsWith("__")) {
      continue
    }

    if ($field.ContainsStandardValue) {
      continue
    }

    $unlinkedFields.Add($field)
  }

  return $unlinkedFields
}

$unlinkedFields = Find-UnlinkedFields -ClonedItem (Get-Item -Path "master:/sitecore/content/path/to/clone")
$unlinkedFields | Format-Table -Property Name, Value
```

More information:

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/determine-if-a-field-contains-standard-values.html